# Cannot search in PDF files created from Crystal reports

Tags: search, pdf, crystal-reports

i am creating a pdf file from crystal reports which is working fine.
But when i want to search a string in the created pdf file it doesn't find anything.
Crystal version used is 13.

any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the CR product name you're using? (XI R2? 2008? 2011?) version numbers started bouncing around after XI...

Comment: Hi Chris, the crystal version installed on the server is 13.